# Can't get link:hover transform to work

Tags: html, css, transform

Here http://davidwalsh.name/css-transformations there's an example of how to use CSS transform to rotate links when you hover but I can't get it to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a:hover{
                font-size:45px;
                -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://davidwalsh.name/css-transformations" target="_blank">text</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I hover the link it does change its font but it wont rotate. I tried using -webkit-transform (I'm using Google Chrome) but it didn't work either.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/cpojer-links.php

I also tried

```
a:link:hover{
         font-size:45px;
         -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
        }
```

but it didn't work either.

I was able to "get it to work" if I put the link in a 'li' and then use li:hover but that's not what I want.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please use standard unprefixed syntax for `transform` at least along with `-webkit`-prefixed one. CSS transforms are supported not only by WebKit-based browsers, but also by IE10+, Opera 12+, and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inline element can't be transformed. You need to make it `display: block` or `display: inline-block`

> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’, ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or ‘table-caption’ [CSS21]

Source: [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transformable-element)

Comment: Any idea why adding border-radius to the hover pseudo class breaks it? It no longer transforms but it does change the border radius...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the transition duration, also I recommend adding support for other browsers as well. I was able to get this code to do what you want it to.

```
a:hover{
    font-size:45px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

[Here's a link](http://jsbin.com/segaqatacuke/1/edit?html,css,output) to a working version of your code.